# Can't customize urls how coca cola does

Tags: facebook, settings

I created this page http://www.facebook.com/pages/Comolakeboats/165976416773845?sk=app_266460616737435 with my iframe application correctly set up. Everything's going well but I can't put it in a pretty url like coca-cola does (http://www.facebook.com/cocacola).

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 25 Likes before your page is eligible to have a custom URL:

[Official Facebook help article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=230372626978166#I-tried-to-secure-a-name-for-my-Page-but-Facebook-said-the-Page-was-not-eligible.-What-are-the-requirements?)

Unfortunately, you can't have pretty URLs for individual iframe application tabs. But if you set a Default Landing Tab then *that tab* will show up by default under the base /pretty-user-name URL (for "non-Likers" - Likers always see the Wall by default).

Comment: I try to set a default landing tab but in page setting - auth privileges I can't find landing tab box..I don't know why. Maybe because I have to wait for 25 likes?

Comment: It looks like you set a default landing tab - when I visit your main page url (http://www.facebook.com/pages/Comolakeboats/165976416773845) I do not land on the wall. So you're good! It will not work for you though, once you have Liked the page. It's only the default for new visitors.

Answer (score 0):

http://it-it.facebook.com/pages/ALCUSTOM/105251819510372 is another example